# Upgrade dual boot XP Pro 32-bit / 7 Home Premium 32-bit to dual boot XP/7 64-bit versions

Tags: boot, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have a dual boot PC (Windows XP Professional / Windows 7 Home Premium 32-bit) on two partitions on my hard drive.

I have recently installed 8GB of RAM; how I can upgrade the whole configuration to Windows XP Professional / Windows 7 64-bit?

Comment: Clean install 64bit over the old 32bit partition.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to upgrade from a 32 bit version of an OS to 64 bit version. You'll need to install the new OSs from scratch.